# Connecting to locally hosted Azure Mobile Services over http from Windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, azure-mobile-services, windows-phone-8.1

I've done this without any issues from my Windows 8 apps but only started seeing this behavior as I'm trying out the 8.1 Universal apps...

I'm well aware of how to do this

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

I have my IIS Express instance setup and I know I can access my locally hosted Azure Mobile Service from my windows phone and windows store app via the IP .... If I go to the browser on the WP8.1 emulator I'm able to navigate to the Mobile Services site hosted on my development machine.

In the windows 8.1 apps though If I try to use the non SSL URI for IIS Express that's just http

```
  new MobileServiceClient("http://IISEXPRESS");
```

then I get this error "{"Only https scheme is allowed.\r\n"}"
at Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions options, Uri requestUri, Uri callbackUri)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.AuthenticationBroker.d__4.MoveNext()

If I switch to using https then it's never able to establish a connection.

```
new MobileServiceClient("https://IISEXPRESS");
```

I'm fairly sure it's an issue with accessing the certificate that IISEXPRESS uses for testing https... Because if I run my app as an 8.1 Store App then I get the same issue.  BUT if I start Fiddler and then run my 8.1 store app then it's able to use the MobileServiceClient over https successfully...  Which I'm pretty sure is due to how fiddler is proxying the https traffic so it can make the certs work.... For example if I navigate to the https url in IE without fiddler I get CERT warnings but if I have fiddler on then I don't get CERT warnings..

This code is pretty much identical to code I have working on a windows phone 8 app that's able to use "http" and I'm able to test locally without any issues...

If i publish my Mobile Service to Azure then all my code works fine as well....

Is there a way to tell the MobileServiceClient that the Web Authentication Broker is ok to use http since it's connecting to a development box? Do I need to make it so the apps can work with the certs generated by IISExpress?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if this might help you, but have you tried creating a new SSL cert for IIS Express? Scott Hanselman has a really great article I followed for debugging middle-tier hosted services.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

Comment: Yea either I did it wrong or it went how I thought. Locally that works great which means I can run the store app and it's happy. But when I go to the https hostname from somewhere else on the network then it gives me a CERT error. WP emulator acts as a separate device on the network so it still suffers the same fate :-(